# Recovery RAID array LVM

Tags: raid, lvm

I have a NAS, the unit became unresponsive so after some research I pulled the drives out of the box, and hooked them up to my Ubuntu box. I now see all 4 drives, and all 4 partitions on the drives. Partition 4 is a RAID 5 array so I used mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdi4 /dev/sdj4 /dev/sdk4 /dev/sdl4 and now it shows md0 as active.

However, this NAS also uses LVM and when I run vgscan, it says "No volume groups found"

I'm stuck, because I cant mount /dev/md0 due to the LVM. Any ideas on what to try next?

Was thinking vgcreate but I think that will blow away the data.

Any ideas are much appreciated!!

UPDATE
I think I got lucky, but here is what I did and it worked:

mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sde4 /dev/sdf4 /dev/sdg4 /dev/sdh4
vgscan
[no volume groups found]
vgcreate DATA /dev/md0 (just created a dummy volume group)
vgchange -a y
[0 active]
lvcreate -L5.45T -n lvo DATA (created a new lv, same size as the original)
lvmdiskscan
[look for /dev/dm-* entries]
file -s /dev/dm-0
mkdir /mnt/raid
mount -t ext3 /dev/dm-0 /mnt/raid
Boom, data was there...

Comment: Tried `pvscan`?

Comment: Huhh, that works sure, but I would not refer to that as best practice.

Answer (score 4):

Run

```
pvscan
pvs
vgs
lvs
```

and tell us about the results.

```
vgchange -ay
```

should activate volume groups in normal circumstances.

All commands are harmless. They will not touch or alter your data.